# CVS : Extra line added at the top in each file

Tags: import, cvs

While importing files in CVS, a header line is added at the top of each imported file.  The format of header line is like this:

$Id: rmutil.c,v 1.1.1.1 2016/05/24 08:19:59 amit Exp $

This leads to problem in comparing the uploaded file with original file as all the imported files become different from their originals.

Does anyone else has also faced similar issue? How can I get rid of such problem?

Comment: Well, I found the answer myself. Its because of keyword substitution. One should use -ko command while importing files in the CVS to avoid keyword substitution altogether. Source : http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/howto/cvsdoc/cvs_12.html#SEC102        and     http://www.badgertronics.com/writings/cvs/keywords.html

Comment: You say a header line is _added_. CVS only expands this if you have an existing `$Id$`. So do you mean not so much that a line was _added_ but that it was _modified_ ("expanded" in CVS terms, in fact)?

Comment: You can always use the `-I <pattern>` parameter to `diff` when comparing anyway, so it's not really an issue.